# creating a pandas dataframe from dictionary of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary of connected components of a graph, for example:

`d = {'A':[1,5,7],'B':[2,4], 'C':[3,6]}`

and I want to create a dataframe of the form:

```
  cc  node
0  A     1
1  A     5
2  A     7
3  B     2
4  B     4
5  C     3
6  C     6
```

I can do this by creating a df for each key in the dictionary and then connecting them, but I am looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `explode`

```
pd.Series(d).explode()
```

Comment: I am trying to create the data frame no the dictionary

Comment: I am getting: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: @BinyaminR update your pandas version ~ explode is after 0.25.0

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'A':[1,5,7],'B':[2,4], 'C':[3,6]}
df = []
for k,v in d.items():
    for i in v:
        df.append([k,i])
for l in df:
    print(l)



['A', 1]
['A', 5]
['A', 7]
['B', 2]
['B', 4]
['C', 3]
['C', 6]
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid looping over all the values

Comment: that doesn't make sense, how would you transform the data without calling each item?

Comment: Pandas implementation is usually faster than using a loop, I don't know about this specific case

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'A':[1,5,7],'B':[2,4], 'C':[3,6]}
temp = [[key, n] for key, val in d.items() for n in val]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['cc', 'node'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  cc  node
0  A     1
1  A     5
2  A     7
3  B     2
4  B     4
5  C     3
6  C     6
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```
cc, node = [], []
for key, value in d.items():
    cc += [key] * len(value)
    node += value
    
df = pd.DataFrame({'cc' : cc, 'node' : node})
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  cc  node
0  A     1
1  A     5
2  A     7
3  B     2
4  B     4
5  C     3
```